# iPhone Mobile Application and Polling / Web Service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, polling

I'm working with an iPhone developer on an application. I know very little about the iPhone. I'm writing the server-side code in Grails. I'm wondering what is available to me as far as approaches to using a RESTful JSON service with an occasional poll of the service.

From the iPhone:
Is there a way to put these calls on a background thread? when the data comes back is there a callback mechanism? Looking for some basic information on how to accomplish this on the iPhone / Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, typically you either provide a delegate that is notified when an asynchronous request has some kind of event (e.g. more data comes in, the request fails, etc.), spawn a background thread that performs synchronous requests, or pass success/failure blocks to an asynchronous request that executes them when appropriate.

But if you are working with an iPhone developer, shouldn't he be dealing with this, not you?

Comment: Guess I should have clarified. Working with someone new to iPhone development. I am using the principle of "Trust but Verify" here. Good answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html). It automatically puts the request on a background thread and has some callback methods that get called on its delegate.

Comment: I'll have a look at that. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using the ASIHttpRequest library for my integrations with RESTful rails apps.  One of many advantages is the completion block:

```
request.completionBlock = ^{ NSLog(@"I'm finally complete!"; };
[request startAsynchronous];
```